# How to easily connect a VS2019 existing project to an existing GitLab empty project

Tags: git, gitlab, visual-studio-2019

I use VS2019 with GitLab. In order to use it, I have first to create the project in GitLab. Then, I have to clone the repository to an empty folder, and finally, I can create the solution to that folder.

But, what if the project is already created in VS2019 with many files inside? I cannot create either a local repository there or clone the GitLab project. In that case, I need to move all files out of the solution folder, clone or create the local repository and then, move the files back to the solution folder.

Is there a simpler way? VS2019 only allows to connect to Azure DevOps, not other GIT server.

I hope I don't need to install an external extension to do such a simple thing.

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was really very easy.

I right-clicked solution node in the solution explorer. Then I chose the option "Add solution to version control". That way, the local repository was created.

Then, I loaded the Configuration dialog of the repository, where I could add the URL of the remote repository.

Finally. I loaded Synchronization dialog, where I could push the local repository to the remote one.

From now on, solution is connected to the remote repository.

That's all and no external extension required.

Regards

Jaime

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you don't want to use another git tool instead of VS's integrated solution? You could use git on the command line or a GUI like SourceTree. Then, turn the local folder into a git repository and add GitLab as remote.

Comment: What visual tool do you recomend? have you used GitLab extension?

Comment: I like SourceTree from Atlassian. Free to use (you have to register though) and it also has an integration with GitLab: https://www.sourcetreeapp.com

Comment: Oh, I have discovered how to do it by myself with no external extension. Thanks anyway.